# Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make a binary search tree using C++. I am using only the functions to insert data and find data.
I can't seem to get the program to work, although I find that it is very logic and correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    struct tree
    {
        tree *leftchild;
        tree *rightchild;
        T data;
    };
    tree *root;
public:
    BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root=NULL; 
    }
    void insert(T);
    void searchForItem(T);
};

template<class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(T newNum)
{
    tree *newItem = new tree; 
    tree *parent; 

    newItem->data = newNum;
    newItem->leftchild = NULL;
    newItem->rightchild = NULL;

    if(root==NULL) 
        root=newItem;

    else
    {
        tree *current;
        current=root;
        while(current) 
        {
            parent = current;

            if(newItem->data > current->data)
                current = current->rightchild;
            else
                current = current->leftchild;
        }

        if(newItem->data > parent->data)
            parent->rightchild = newItem;
        else
            parent->leftchild = newItem;
    }

}

template<class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::searchForItem(T toFindNum)
{
    tree *current;
    tree *parent;

    current = root;
    if(current->data == toFindNum)
        cout<<toFindNum<<" is the root of this binary search tree."<<endl;

    while(current->data != toFindNum)
    {
        parent = current;

        if(current->data > toFindNum)
            current = current->rightchild;
        else
            current = current->leftchild;
    }

    cout<<toFindNum<<" is the child of "<<parent->data<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> b;

    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(4);
    b.insert(3);
    b.insert(2);
    b.insert(7);

    b.searchForItem(4);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or the error you are facing?

Comment: It is very helpful to have a print() method in your tree class.  Then after each insert() you can do a print() to see if the tree looks like you expect.

Comment: Belongs on http://www.debug-my-code-plz.com

Comment: Please use a debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem before posting a question on Stack Overflow. ;)

Answer (score 6):

One problem is here.

```
if(current->data > toFindNum)
    current = current->rightchild;
```

Consider this tree.

```
  5
 /  \
 4   6
```

Your `toFindNum` is 4. If `current->data` is 5, greater than 4, you need to look in the left child, not right one.

Your statement should be this.

```
if(current->data > toFindNum)
    current = current->leftchild;
else
current = current->rightchild;
```

Comment: More generally, `current->data` should be on the same side of the `>` sign in both `insert` and `find`.

Comment: So the right one is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In `searchForItem`

```
if(current->data > toFindNum)
```

shouldn't that be:

```
if (toFindNum > current->data)
```

Comment: The code worked as Coding Mash said, thank you.